# Delayed-Job not running in development machine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm trying to run `rake jobs:work` or from the console `Delayed::Worker.new.start` to start a DelayedJob process in my development environment and I'm having this weird error:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.9.3-head :001 > Delayed::Worker.new.start
Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=410
  @request_id=2
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="hapievents.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:findAndModify=>"delayed_backend_mongoid_jobs", :query=>{"run_at"=>{"$lte"=>2012-11-19 23:52:23 UTC}, "failed_at"=>nil, "$or"=>[{"locked_by"=>"host:Nunix-Netbook pid:11867"}, {"locked_at"=>nil}, {"locked_at"=>{"$lt"=>2012-11-19 19:52:23 UTC}}]}, :new=>true, :sort=>{"locked_by"=>-1, "priority"=>1, "run_at"=>1}, :update=>{"$set"=>{:locked_at=>2012-11-19 23:52:23 UTC, :locked_by=>"host:Nunix-Netbook pid:11867"}}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error "no such cmd"
```

I think the problem is with Mongo. I'm using the gem `delayed_job_mongoid`.
At first I thought it was a problem with a certain job, but now my job list is empty and I can't start the DelayedJob *server*.